# Why is my unreduced retirement date same as the normal retirement date

Tags: canada, retirement

My employer says that my unreduced retirement date is the same as normal retirement date (at age 65).

How come some people have unreduced retirement date that is upto 5 yrs sooner than their normal retirement date?

Comment: What is an "unreduced retirement date"?

Comment: Some employees (based on conditions which I am trying to figure out) can retire before 65 with a full (unreduced) pension. That is the origin of the term.

Comment: If you really mean pension rather than social security or 401k/IRA, that''s specific to your company's pension. Ask your HR department.